# Cannot format numbers after migration to struts 2

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, number-formatting, struts-1

I am working on a migration from Struts 1 to Struts 2. The thing is that the migration is "finished" but not tested. I am responsible of bugfixing after the test.
We encountered a weird problem. The project with struts1 was doing the formatting of numbers automatically so whenever I was writing 1.0 or 1,0 struts was accepting both values or if I was writing 36,000 struts was taking 36000. But on the new version with Struts2 this is not happening and sadly I cannot ask the guys who made the previous phase as they don't work with me anymore. Example, if I write 36,000 on a  `<s:textfield>` struts just takes 0.0.

Before (working fine):

```
<html:text property="newRemun.inEmploymentTax2" style="width: 200px;"
  errorStyleClass="inputError"value="${remunIncomeForm.newRemun.formattedInEmploymentTax2}" 
  readonly="${readonlyValue and not (edit4Eav or edit4Value)}" 
  disabled="${readonlyValue and not (edit4Eav or edit4Value)}"></html:text>
```

After (not formatting correctly):

```
<s:textfield name="newRemun.inEmploymentTax2" value="%{newRemun.formattedInEmploymentTax2}" 
  style="width: 200px;" readonly="#readonlyFlag" disabled="#readonlyFlag"
  cssErrorClass="inputError"/>
```

So my question is: is there somewhere where I can check if there are any configurations related to number formatting?

Important to know: I have already debugged everything, and from the getters and setters from the struts form, in the former version I get the correct value and on the current version I don't get the formatted value. And there is no JS formatting those values. So basically the problem is before the values reach the form.

The problem also is that our application is used worldwide therefore the user inputs are quite different regarding the country, but until now there were no problems but after we made a "test deployment" users from Japan for example were inputting quantities such us "36,000,000" and Struts2 got crazy.

Any help or ideas are welcome!! Also ideas to try to find the solution :)

Comment: hi Roman, thanks for the help. I knew about this topic but did not know about the i18n filter. However I dont think this is my problem as internationalization is working in our project (we have different strings for different languages). The issue is how the values are formated when they come from the user input (specific format given by user) till they are converted in a struts form (generic format for java).

Comment: It depends on the locale.